# Adding Contacts via sync adapter

Tags: android, contacts, mime-types, android-contacts, android-syncadapter

I've added custom contacts via a sync adapter.
I have 2 actions i want to do on the contact from the native contact application.
After adding the actions when i click the contact avatar(image) i get a screen with quick actions. 
Problem is i get 2 icons for my actions and both of them are not what i specified...
both of them are the app's icon.

Where can i define it to show on all phones the same way? 
[1] : http://www.androidpatterns.com/wp-content/uploads/contacts2-180x300.png "example"

Comment: what do you suggest me adding to the title?

Answer (score 0):

When using custom actions we need to declare 
intent filter to catch the event(button click)

```
 <intent-filter android:icon="@drawable/icon_click1">
   <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
   <data android:mimeType="vnd.android.cursor.item/my.app.go.click1" />
   <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
 </intent-filter>
```

we add the android:icon and then the contacts app shows it.